# How to select all rows in a dataframe between two values of column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a Dataframe like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame([['travail','hk','hj'],['test',6,6],[5,5,8],[4,3,1],['moyenne',5,6],[5,6,7],
         [1,2,3],['travail','test','kkj'],[5,'hjjd',8],['moyenne',6,7],[5,5,8],[4,3,1],['hkk',5,6],[5,5,8],
         [7,8,5]],columns=['A','B','C'])
```

I want to select all line between `travail` and `moyennee` in column A and obtain :

```
         A     B    C
0   travail    hk   hj
1      test     6    6
2         5     5    8
3         4     3    1
4   moyenne     5    6
7   travail  test  kkj
8         5  hjjd    8
9   moyenne     6    7
```

How can I do that?

Comment: You should accept an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Compare column by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) (`==`), second change ordering by [`Series.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iloc.html), get [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) and compare again by [`Series.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html) (`>`), chain mask by `&` for bitwise `AND`, last filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
m1 = df['A'].eq('travail').cumsum().gt(0)
m2 = df['A'].eq('moyenne').iloc[::-1].cumsum().gt(0)

df1 = df[m1 & m2]
print (df1)
         A     B    C
0  travail    hk   hj
1     test     6    6
2        5     5    8
3        4     3    1
4  moyenne     5    6
5        5     6    7
6        1     2    3
7  travail  test  kkj
8        5  hjjd    8
9  moyenne     6    7
```

If exist always both values in column `A` is possible use [`Series.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html) with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
a = df['A'].eq('travail').idxmax()
b = df['A'].eq('moyenne').iloc[::-1].idxmax()

df1 = df.loc[a:b]
```

Answer (score 1):

One can use `for` loop with `iloc` to check each row and append rows within desired blocks to a new empty dataframe:

```
newdf = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)
flag = False
for i in range(len(df)): 
    firstval = df.iloc[i,0]
    if firstval == 'travail': 
        newdf = newdf.append(df.iloc[i,:])
        flag = True
    elif firstval == 'moyenne':
        newdf = newdf.append(df.iloc[i,:])
        flag = False
    elif flag==True: 
        newdf = newdf.append(df.iloc[i,:])
print(newdf)
```

Output:

```
         A     B    C
0  travail    hk   hj
1     test     6    6
2        5     5    8
3        4     3    1
4  moyenne     5    6
7  travail  test  kkj
8        5  hjjd    8
9  moyenne     6    7
```